# Passing argument to Backgroundworker error handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables, backgroundworker

My program has to test several products in different slots simultaneously. When there's an error in a slot like accidental detachment from the computer, the program is suppose to log the error type and the serial number of the product that has been provided by the user when starting up the UI into a textfile.

I'm using Background Worker to handle the multi-threading. While I have managed to log the error type using e.Error, I can't seem to figure out how to pass the serial number from the DoWork function to the Background Worker error handler.

I tried googling for a solution but it seems like nobody has asked this before. I will really appreciate any help given.
PS: I'm quite new to C# so be gentle haha :)

Below is an example code:

```
        private void startAsync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                // Start the asynchronous operation.
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private void cancelAsync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
            {
                // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            int b = 0; //simulate error
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    string[] array2 = { "1", "cancelled" };
                    e.Result = array2; //passing values when user cancel through e.Result object
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                    worker.ReportProgress(i * 10, "Test a");
                    int a = 1 / b; //simulate error
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
                string[] array1 = {"1","done"};
                e.Result = array1; //passing values when complete through e.Result object
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%" + e.UserState.ToString();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                string[] someArray2 = e.Result as string[];
                string sernum = someArray2[0];
                string status = someArray2[1];
                resultLabel.Text = sernum + " " + status;
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                resultLabel.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message; //how to pass sernum here?
            }
            else
            {
                string[] someArray = e.Result as string[];
                string sernum = someArray[0];
                string status = someArray[1];
                resultLabel.Text = sernum + " " + status;

            }
        }
```

Comment: You are already passing data from DoWork to `RunWorkerCompleted`. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Have you ever considered to switch out from `BackgroundWorker` to TPL and `async/await`?

Comment: @VMAtm what are the advantages of using async/wait? I'm still using backgroundworker in my program

Comment: `async/await` will not require the thread for the IO operations, background worker will. Also, the code will be rather easy than yours. Also, cancellation logic via TPL is easy than yours, and you do not need to use the `Sleep.Wait`. Side note: `if (worker.CancellationPending == true)` is equivalent to `if (worker.CancellationPending)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to get data back to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler in the case of an exception.

IMHO, the most natural from a semantic point of view is to put the data in the exception itself. For example:

```
class BackgroundWorkerException : Exception
{
    public string Sernum { get; }

    public BackgroundWorkerException(string sernum, Exception inner)
        : base("DoWork event handler threw an exception", inner)
    {
        Sernum = sernum;
    }
}
```

Then in your `DoWork` handler:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    try
    {
        int b = 0; //simulate error
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                string[] array2 = { "1", "cancelled" };
                e.Result = array2; //passing values when user cancel through e.Result object
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                worker.ReportProgress(i * 10, "Test a");
                int a = 1 / b; //simulate error
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }
            string[] array1 = {"1","done"};
            e.Result = array1; //passing values when complete through e.Result object
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new BackgroundWorkerException("1", e);
    }
}
```

Finally, in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled == true)
    {
        string[] someArray2 = e.Result as string[];
        string sernum = someArray2[0];
        string status = someArray2[1];
        resultLabel.Text = sernum + " " + status;
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        string sernum = ((BackgroundWorkerException)e.Error).Sernum;

        resultLabel.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
    }
    else
    {
        string[] someArray = e.Result as string[];
        string sernum = someArray[0];
        string status = someArray[1];
        resultLabel.Text = sernum + " " + status;

    }
}
```

Your question isn't clear about what `sernum` actually represents, and in particular whether it's a single value for a given background task, or a single task could have more than one value for `sernum`. If it's the former, i.e. you know when you start the task what the value is, then you could pass it directly to the event handlers by capturing it in an anonymous method used for each actual event handler.

That approach won't work though in your specific scenario without some changes. You appear to have added a single `BackgroundWorker` object to your form as a component and are reusing it. Using an anonymous method works better/more easily if you are creating a new `BackgroundWorker` each time, so that you can subscribe your anonymous method delegate to `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted`. (You have to subscribe it just before each invocation because, presumably, the `sernum` value is different each time.)

You could get it to work with the single component added to the form in the Designer as you're doing here, but it's a lot more complicated because you have to dynamically add a handler to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event which unsubscribes both itself and the delegates you subscribed to the `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events (you wouldn't subscribe any methods directly to the component in the Designer, in this scheme).

Another alternative is to create a custom data structure passed as the argument for `RunWorkerAsync()`, which can contain a property for the `sernum` value. You can set this value in the method that starts the worker, or in the `DoWork` event handler.

This approach fits only a little better with the component-in-Designer scenario you have, because you still need a way to get the reference to that custom data structure back to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler, which you can do only by storing it in e.g. an instance field that can be shared between the `Click` event handler that starts the worker and the `RunWorkerCompleted` event (and frankly, if you do that, at that point it's debatable whether it's even worth it to pass that reference to the `RunWorkerAsync()` method, since the `DoWork` event handler could get at the same instance field just as well.)

Another alternative is to catch the exception as I've done in my code example above, but then instead of rethrowing the exception, treat it as if the work was cancelled (i.e. set the `Result` and `Cancel` properties).

Yet another approach is to abandon `BackgroundWorker` altogether and switch to the TPL `Task`-based idiom. That doesn't solve the problem implicitly, but it allows any of the above options, as well as the option of just defining your own mode for passing errors back.

If you need more specific help than that, you'll need to post a new question, with a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows which of the above approaches you've attempted to try, or some other alternative not listed here, and what *specifically* you're unable to figure out.

Answer (score -1):

See code below.  You don't need a class.  Can simple send a string or int using similar code.

```
        public class Parameters
        {
            public string message = "";
        }

        private void startAsync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                // Start the asynchronous operation.
                Parameters parameters = new Parameters() { message = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" };


                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(parameters);
            }
        }



        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Parameters parameters = e.Argument as Parameters;
        }
```